# Import/export high rank numpy array to text file

Tags: python, numpy, io, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy.ndarray with a high rank - say, for example, the shape `(100,100,100,2)`.  What is the best way to write it to a text file so that it will be easy to import in other programs as well as numpy?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26235114/832621) explains how to use `np.savetxt()` to deal with multi-dimensional arrays, fitting with your purposes...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.savetxt` if you flatten the array and include the array shape in the header so its the first line). That way you know how to reshape the array when you open it in some other program:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(100,100,100,2)
np.savetxt('test.txt', a.flatten(), header=str(a.shape))
```

To import the data and reshape it, you could do the following, for example:

```
import re
with open('test.txt') as f:
    shape = tuple(int(num) for num in re.findall(r'\d+', f.readline()))
data = np.loadtxt('test.txt').reshape(shape)
```

Comment: This is what I've been doing.  I was hoping there was a better way, but this might be the best.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tofile`, also part of `numpy` ([link to doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile)). To read a binary simply use `fromfile`, [doc here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html#numpy.fromfile).

I'm not sure about portability but if speed matters writing binaries is the better option.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(100,100,100,2)
a.tofile('test.txt')
```

Comment: There has been a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8775786/1498309) on stack overflow before. Check this out for other options as well.

Comment: The issue is not so much the size or speed, but portability.  If I want to read the binary file with another program, I'm going to have some issues I think.  Your link did point me to the HDF5 format, which might serve my purposes.  However, in the question I did specify a text file, which this answer doesn't use.